# Python/Openpyxl copy and paste columns with formula

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a workbook with a worksheet, named sheet #1. I want to copy some columns from sheet #1 and change column orders a little bit.
First, I create a new worksheet, named sheet #2. I can copy and paste from sheet #1 to sheet #2, but I find `openpyxl` copies formulas exactly as is, so I have a problem. For example, column `O` in sheet #1 has some formula like:

> O3=(M3*1)+(N3*1)

I move column `M` in sheet #1 to column H in sheet #2 and move column `N` in sheet #1 to column I in sheet #2. When I move column O in sheet #1 to column `M` in sheet #2, I have problems. Firstly, column `M` in sheet #2's formula is still:

> M3=(M3*1)+(N3*1)

I have a circular reference issue since I try to use myself to calculate myself. Secondly, if I move column `O` in sheet #1 to column `J` in sheet #2, I don't have this circular reference problem, but my formula is still messed up.

I use the following way to copy and paste:

```py
for i in range(0, 1000):

     sheet_#2.cell(row=i,column=12).value = sheet_#1.cell(row=i,column=14).value
```

I have tried `data_only` with `true` and `false` when I call `load_workbook` as follows.

```py
  my_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(args.input_file, data_only=False)
```

Neither works for me. `True` gets me all zeros in both sheet #1 and sheet #2. `False` gets me the circular reference problem as described above.

Is there a way to use `openpyxl` package to solve my problem? I think as long as when copying and pasting, if worksheet name can be added to specify the cells in the formula, my problem is solved, something like this:

> M3=("Sheet #1"M3*1)+("Sheet #1"N3*1)

If `openpyxl` doesn't do the job, is there a better package to solve this problem? `pandas`?

Answer (score 0):

I will start off by saying I am no expert, but I'll give it a go.

By the sound of your question it seems you may not be familiar with Pandas. I would tackle this with pandas. Also do some additional reading on Pandas it is so powerful! Especially for excel automation.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the excel sheets to Pandas DataFrames
DataFrame1 = pd.read_excel("FileName.xlsx", sheetname='sheet_number_1')
DataFrame2 = pd.read_excel("FileName.xlsx", sheetname='sheet_number_2')
```

You should read your sheet #2 DataFrame and bring over columns that ***DO NOT*** have formulas from your sheet#1 DataFrame first.

```
#You can set columns equal to each other like this.
sheet2df['sheet_2_column_name'] = sheet1df['sheet_1_column_name']
```

This will bring over all data from whatever sheet 1 column you choose into whatever sheet 2 column you choose.

Now for columns ***with formulas***... You mentioned the formula `(M3*1)+(N3*1)` will now become `(H3*1)+(I3*1)` in your sheet#2. I wouldn't bring these columns over using above method instead I would do something like this...

```
#apply formula down each row in a column
DataFrame2['column_name_to_insert_formula_to'] = DataFrame2.apply(lambda row: '(H{}*1)+(I{}*1)'.format(row.name + 2), axis=1)
```

In this case you can leave the {} blank. This formula will iterate down the row number in the `{}` brackets. You are essentially passing `.format(row.name +2)` which in this case is your row number as a parameter into the brackets. Also we use axis=1 because you want to apply it to each row in a column. axis=1 will do that for us.

More info on Pandas .apply function from the Pandas docs
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

More info on Apply and Lambda usage in Pandas
https://towardsdatascience.com/apply-and-lambda-usage-in-pandas-b13a1ea037f7

Comment: I have never used pandas, so I have no experience. I heard it is more powerful and I just like to confirm it can solve my problem with pandas. It seems so. But my issue is pandas is not installed in our system and I cannot install it by myself:(. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Why are you unable to install? I find it odd that you’d be allowed to install openpyxl and python, but not Pandas. I’d recommend reaching out to whoever does have control of this and push them to allow you to install this packages it will benefit you and many others. Good luck!